# why can't List<? extends List<T>> be assigned to List<List<T>>

Tags: java, generics

My class has a property that is a two dimensinal list of a certain class `T`.

It seems that it is logical to create this property as a `List<? extends List<T>>`, thus allowing it to be assigned `List<ArrayList<T>>` or `List<LinkedList<T>` in addition to `List<List<T>>`.

It also seems logical that my getter will return a `List<List<T>>`, since we don't need to tell Consumers that what this list can be assigned since the consumer will asign the object he gets from the getter to a variable, and not the other way around.

However, my getter refuses to automatically convert `List<? extends List<T>>` to `List<List<T>>`, throwing an IncompatibleType error. Why can't it be coerced?

Comment: i think you should tag this question as Java

Comment: Here's why: `List<LinkedList<T>> list = new ArrayList<>(); List<? extends List<T>> list2 = list; List<List<T>> list3 = list2; list3.add(new ArrayList<T>());`. So, if it was accepted, you would be able to add an ArrayList to a list of linked lists. A List<? extends whatever> is a List of some specific type, but you don't know what it is. Since you don't know, you can't add anything to it.

Comment: " since we don't need to tell Consumers that what this list can be assigned" ... ```List<? extends List<T>>``` is less specific than ```List<List<T>>``` so the former return type is more in-line with the policy of telling the user as little are possible```.

Comment: I would add that if the user of getter is not going to add elements to the individual list in the list returned then you could go even further and return ```List<? extends List<? extends T>>```. Then you could change the field and setter method signatures accordingly your class in not going to alter their content either.

Answer (score 1):

[@JB-Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) explained the reason pretty well: it would allow you to add an `ArrayList` to a list of `LinkedList` -s.

The short answer is, of course, you cannot do that because the compiler will not let you do that ;)

Let me show you another example. You basically cannot add anything to such collections:

```
List<? extends List<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new LinkedList<T>()); // compile error
list.add(new ArrayList<T>()); // compile error
List<T> sublist = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(sublist); // compile error
```

If this is what you want, then you can just use whatever list type within your getter and return the wildcard-type:

```
public List<? extends List<T>> getSomething() {
    List<ArrayList<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // do something
    return list; // List<ArrayList<T>> converts automatically to List<? extends List<T>
}
```

If you want clients to **add** stuff to this list but not remove, then you can use the `super` keyword:

```
List<? super ArrayList<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ArrayList<T>()); // this is fine
```

On the other hand, if you want to allow both operations, then simply don't use a wildcard:

```
public List<List<T>> getSomething() {
    return new ArrayList<>();'
}
```